# Update specific file in RPM, how does --change-files option work?

Tags: rpm

I'm trying to repack a RPM package with rpmrebuild command, according to the manual I can update files with `--change-files` option.

```
--change-files="pgm1 a b c"
```

But the manual didn't say much about the parameter above, what does it mean?

e.g If I want to update $RPM_ROOT/etc/default.conf with /tmp/test.conf, what arguments should I use?